# Semantically disambiguating an ambiguous syntax

Tags: antlr4

Using Antlr 4 I have a situation I am not sure how to resolve.  I originally asked the question at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/antlr-discussion/1yxxxAvU678 on the Antlr discussion forum.  But that forum does not seem to get a lot of traffic, so I am asking again here.

I have the following grammar:

```
expression
    : ...
    | path
    ;

path
    : ...
    | dotIdentifierSequence
    ;

dotIdentifierSequence 
    : identifier (DOT identifier)*
    ;
```

The concern here is that `dotIdentifierSequence` can mean a number of things semantically, and not all of them are "paths".  But at the moment they are all recognized as paths in the parse tree and then I need to handle them specially in my visitor.

But what I'd really like is a way to express the dotIdentifierSequence usages that are not paths into the `expression` rule rather than in the `path` rule, and still have dotIdentifierSequence in path to handle path usages.

To be clear, a dotIdentifierSequence might be any of the following:

1. A path - this is a SQL-like grammar and a path expression would be like a table or column reference in SQL, e.g. `a.b.c`
2. A Java class name - e.g. `com.acme.SomeJavaType`
3. A static Java field reference - e.g. `com.acme.SomeJavaType.SOME_FIELD`
4. A Java enum value reference - e.g. `com.acme.Gender.MALE`

The idea is that during visitation "dotIdentifierSequence as a path" resolves as a very different type from the other usages.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you're trying to make a distinction between "paths" while being created in the parser. Constructing paths inside the lexer would be easier (pseudo code follows):

```antlr
grammar T;

tokens {
  JAVA_TYPE_PATH,
  JAVA_FIELD_PATH
}

// parser rules

PATH
 : IDENTIFIER ('.' IDENTIFIER)*
   {
     String s = getText();
     if (s is a Java class) {
       setType(JAVA_TYPE_PATH);
     } else if (s is a Java field) {
       setType(JAVA_FIELD_PATH);
     }
   }
 ;

fragment IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
```

and then in the parser you would do:

```antlr
expression
 : JAVA_TYPE_PATH   #javaTypeExpression
 | JAVA_FIELD_PATH  #javaFieldExpression  
 | PATH             #pathExpression
 ;
```

But then, of course, input like this `java./*comment*/lang.String` would be tokenized wrongly.

Handling it all in the parser would mean manually looking ahead in the token stream and checking if either a Java type, or field exists.

A quick demo:

```antlr
grammar T;

@parser::members {

  String getPathAhead() {

    Token token = _input.LT(1);

    if (token.getType() != IDENTIFIER) {
      return null;
    }

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(token.getText());

    // Try to collect ('.' IDENTIFIER)*
    for (int stepsAhead = 2; ; stepsAhead += 2) {

      Token expectedDot = _input.LT(stepsAhead);
      Token expectedIdentifier = _input.LT(stepsAhead + 1);

      if (expectedDot.getType() != DOT || expectedIdentifier.getType() != IDENTIFIER) {
        break;
      }

      builder.append('.').append(expectedIdentifier.getText());
    }

    return builder.toString();
  }

  boolean javaTypeAhead() {

    String path = getPathAhead();

    if (path == null) {
      return false;
    }

    try {
      return Class.forName(path) != null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  boolean javaFieldAhead() {

    String path = getPathAhead();

    if (path == null || !path.contains(".")) {
      return false;
    }

    int lastDot = path.lastIndexOf('.');
    String typeName = path.substring(0, lastDot);
    String fieldName = path.substring(lastDot + 1);

    try {
      Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(typeName);
      return clazz.getField(fieldName) != null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

expression
 : {javaTypeAhead()}?  path    #javaTypeExpression
 | {javaFieldAhead()}? path    #javaFieldExpression
 | path                        #pathExpression
 ;

path
 : dotIdentifierSequence
 ;

dotIdentifierSequence
 : IDENTIFIER (DOT IDENTIFIER)*
 ;

IDENTIFIER
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;

DOT
 : '.'
 ;
```

which can be tested with the following class:

```java
package tl.antlr4;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.NotNull;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] tests = {
            "mu",
            "tl.antlr4.The",
            "java.lang.String",
            "foo.bar.Baz",
            "tl.antlr4.The.answer",
            "tl.antlr4.The.ANSWER"
        };

        for (String test : tests) {
            TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(test));
            TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
            ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new TestListener(), parser.expression());
        }
    }
}

class TestListener extends TBaseListener {

    @Override
    public void enterJavaTypeExpression(@NotNull TParser.JavaTypeExpressionContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("JavaTypeExpression  -> " + ctx.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void enterJavaFieldExpression(@NotNull TParser.JavaFieldExpressionContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("JavaFieldExpression -> " + ctx.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void enterPathExpression(@NotNull TParser.PathExpressionContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("PathExpression      -> " + ctx.getText());
    }
}

class The {
    public static final int ANSWER = 42;
}
```

which would print the following to the console:

```
PathExpression      -> mu
JavaTypeExpression  -> tl.antlr4.The
JavaTypeExpression  -> java.lang.String
PathExpression      -> foo.bar.Baz
PathExpression      -> tl.antlr4.The.answer
JavaFieldExpression -> tl.antlr4.The.ANSWER
```

Comment: Ah, I never considered moving this to the lexer.  Although it makes perfect sense as really these all represent different token types.  Thanks for the inventive solution!

Comment: From the question I assumed that the OP is already doing this kind of check to find out if such an identifier is a path or a class/type reference and wanted a different solution. Btw. from a functional standpoint it makes no difference if you have this check in the parser or in the lexer, but having it in the lexer means: manual whitespace handling.